# Why does Case/When ungroup the results of my values() annotate() query?

Tags: python, django

I have a conditional query question.  I've been reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/ and can't seem to figure this out.

Let's say I have an Order model, and I want a payment breakdown grouped by user.

Here's the Order model:

```
class Order(models.Model):    
    CASH = 'c'
    CARD = 'a'
    PAYMENT_TYPES = (
        (CASH, 'Cash'),
        (CARD, 'Card'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PAYMENT_TYPES)
    grand_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

Here's a values() + annotate() query showing me the total per user:

```
query = Order.objects.values(
    'user'
).annotate(
    total=Sum('grand_total'),
)
```

The result, so far so good:

```
User     Total
--------------
User 1   300
User 2   250
```

However, when I add Case/When conditions to the query:

```
query = Order.objects.values(
    'user'
).annotate(
    cash=Case(When(payment_type=Order.CASH, then=Sum('grand_total')), default=Value(0)),
    card=Case(When(payment_type=Order.CARD, then=Sum('grand_total')), default=Value(0)),
    total=Sum('grand_total'),
)
```

I get this result, which is not what I want:

```
User     Cash      Card      Total
----------------------------------
User 1   300       0         300
User 2   200       0         200
User 2   0         50        50
```

Of course, this is what I want:

```
User     Cash      Card      Total
----------------------------------
User 1   300       0         300
User 2   200       50        250
```

Why is the Case/When undoing the GROUP BY that values() is giving me?

Note: The Order model doesn't have default ordering, but just in case, upon reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by when using values(), I've tried adding `.order_by()` and `.order_by('user')` to my query, which did not change the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my aggregate functions should wrap my Case statement, and not the other way around.

```
query = Order.objects.values(
    'user',
).annotate(
    cash=Sum(Case(When(payment_type=Order.CASH, then=F('grand_total')))),
    card=Sum(Case(When(payment_type=Order.CARD, then=F('grand_total')))),
    total=Sum('grand_total'),
)
```